# Selenium WebDriverJS thenCatch not catching StaleElementException

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am running node.js and Selenium WebDriverJS. One of my tests is failing with the following error:

```
UnknownError: unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: Error: element is not attached to the page document
```

I understand that this is essentially a StaleElementReferenceException, but I have not been able to find a reliable workaround. I have tried the following without success:

1. waiting for the element to appear on the page before finding and clicking on the element

   ```
   waitForElement: function (selector, timeout) {
       if (typeof(timeout) === 'undefined') { timeout = 3000; }
       driver.wait(function() {
           return driver.findElements(selector).then(function(list) {
               return list.length > 0;
           });
       }, timeout);
   }
   ```
2. waiting an explicit time period (`driver.sleep(1000)`) before finding and clicking on the element
3. finding the element multiple times (using `.findElement()`) before clicking on the element
4. using a promise chain to catch any errors and try re-clicking on the element

   ```
   driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
       driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath(...)).click();
   }).thenCatch(function(e) {
       driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath(...)).click();
   });
   ```
5. using a promise chain with a recursive function to keep trying to re-click the element

   ```
   var getStaleElement = function(selector, callback) {
       var element = driver.findElement(selector);
       callback(element);
   }).thenCatch(function(e) {
       getStaleElement(selector, callback);
   });

   var clickSelf = function(ele) { return ele.click() };

   driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
       driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath(...)).click();
   }).thenCatch(function(e) {
       getStaleElement(webdriver.By.xpath(...), clickSelf);
   });
   ```
6. methods 4 and 5 using the errback argument of `.then()` in place of `.thenCatch()`
7. combinations of the above

It seems like Selenium is not able to catch this specific error. I used print statements to confirm that other errors such as NoSuchElementError are caught by `.thenCatch()`. Is there a workaround that will allow me to deal with stale elements?

Comment: I forgot to mention in the original post that this error does not come up every time I run the test, but only occasionally.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, so I made the below work-around, you can give it a try ...

```
/*
 * params.config - {
 *           opposite - {Boolean} - if true, will wait till negative result is reached/ error is thrown.
 *           maxWaitTime - {Number} - if this time exceeds, just throw an error and leave.
 *           waitTime - {Number} - wait time between two checks.
 *           expectValue - {Boolean} - where you just want it to run without error, or it should expect a value
 *           expectedValue - {Object} - object value it should or should not match.
 *         }
 *  params.fn - a function that returns a promise that we want to keep checking till desire value is reached
 */
function waiter(fn, config){
    config = config || {};
    var deffered = Driver.promise.defer(),  
        wt = config.waitTime || 100,
        mwt = config.maxWaitTime || 3000,
        timeoutReached = false,
        pCall = function(){
                        fn().then(pThen, pCatch);
                    },
        pThen = function(data){
                    if(timeoutReached)  return;
                    if(config.expectValue){
                        if(config.opposite){                        
                            if(data == config.expectedValue){
                                setTimeout(pCall, wt);
                            }else{
                                clearTimeout(vTimeout);
                                deffered.fulfill(true);
                            }
                        }else{
                            if(data == config.expectedValue){
                                clearTimeout(vTimeout);
                                deffered.fulfill(true);
                            }else{
                                setTimeout(pCall, wt);
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        deffered.fulfill(true);
                    }
                },  
        pCatch = function(err){
                    if(timeoutReached)  return;
                    if(config.opposite){
                        deffered.fulfill(true);
                    }else{
                        setTimeout(pCall, wt);
                    }
                };  

    pCall();    

    var vTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
        timeoutReached = true;
        if(config.opposite){
            deffered.fulfill(true);         
        }else{
            deffered.reject(new Error('timed-out'));
        }
    }, mwt);
    return deffered.promise;
}
```

example usage( for your case):

```
var myPromise = function(){
    return driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath(...)).click();
};

//default use
waiter(myPromise).then(function(){
    console.log('finally...');
}).catch(fucntion(err){
    console.log('not working: ', err);
});

// with custom timeout after 10 seconds
waiter(myPromise, {maxWaitTime: 10000}).then(function(){
    console.log('finally...');
}).catch(fucntion(err){
    console.log('not working: ', err);
});
```

Comment: I tried implementing your work-around, but the same error
`UnknownError: unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: Error: element is not attached to the page document` is still coming up.
I changed the `.catch(...)` to `.thenCatch(...)` to make things compile, but `console.log('not working: ', err);` is not logging anything. Any ideas as to why this might be happening?

Comment: @eytac, the thing is, I do not understand how the error propagates, because the way I have implemented, it will keep trying when error occurs, till a timeout is reached( only error possible must be timeout error)... i dont understand how you get `UnknownError: unknown error:`

Comment: I had originally tried writing a recursive function that should have kept trying when an error occurs (method 5 above), but it seems like this error is not being caught for whatever reason so the errback argument in your `pCall()` function seems like it isn't being called.

Comment: I just added a `console.log()` statement at the beginning of the `pCatch()` function, but nothing is logged, so `pCatch()` is not being called when the error comes up.

Comment: you could give this a try `var button = driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xxx(someSelector), 10000);
button.click();`

Comment: Due to the asynchronous nature of the code, this was giving me lots of `TypeError`s, which prevented the test from actually running in some cases, even when I tried reformatting some things. I forgot to mention in the original post that this error does not come up every time I run the test, but only occasionally. Maybe this information is of use in some way?

Comment: i have always found that promises are a good solution to the async problem, also ddi you try the code from my previous comment?

Comment: Yes, I tried to chain promises with `var button = driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xxx(someSelector)), 10000); button.click();` but I was getting `TypeError`s

Comment: i left it as `xxx` as I did not know what type of selector you wanted,  replace it with id, css or something...

Comment: I replaced it with `xpath` and a valid selector, but the issue was that button wasn't a webelement so `.click()` was throwing a `TypeError`. Regardless, the `UnknownError` is still coming up.

Comment: Edit: `UnknownError` still occasionally comes up even when navigating from different pages to the page with the stale element.

Answer (score 1):

You had the right idea with `getStaleElement` but did not code it correctly. Here is something that works:

```
function retryOnStale(selector, callback) {
    return browser.findElement(selector).then(callback)
        .thenCatch(function (err) {
            if (err.name === 'StaleElementReferenceError')
                return retryOnStale(selector, callback);

            throw err;
        });
}
```

Here is code that demonstrates its use. You'll find `retryOnStaleIllustrate`  contains code that will cause a stale element exception to occur and it has a `console.log` for diagnosis. Then there is `retryOnStale` which is the same as what I've shown above.

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
var By = webdriver.By;
var until = webdriver.until;

var browser = new chrome.Driver();

browser.get("http://www.example.com");

function make_stale() {
    browser.executeScript("document.body.innerHTML = " +
                          "'<p id=\\'foo\\'>foo text</p>'");
}

// Create our initial p element with id `foo`.
make_stale();

var fake_stale = 10;

// We have to use var ... = ... because later in this code we are
// going to change the value of retryOnStaleIllustrate.
function retryOnStaleIllustrate(selector, callback) {
    return browser.findElement(selector).then(function (element) {

        //
        // This code is here to simulate a process that causes the element
        // we acquired to become stale.
        //
        if (fake_stale) {
            make_stale();
            fake_stale--;
        }

        return callback(element);
    }).thenCatch(function (err) {
        if (err.name === 'StaleElementReferenceError') {
            console.log("stale: retrying");
            return retryOnStaleIllustrate(selector, callback);
        }

        throw err;
    });
}

retryOnStaleIllustrate(By.id("foo"), function (element) {
    element.getText().then(console.log);
});

// Once we remove the code to simulate an element becoming stale, and
// the console.log for diagnosis, this is what we are left with:
function retryOnStale(selector, callback) {
    return browser.findElement(selector).then(callback)
        .thenCatch(function (err) {
            if (err.name === 'StaleElementReferenceError')
                return retryOnStale(selector, callback);

            throw err;
        });
}

// This just shows that retryOnStale returns a promise which can be used.
retryOnStale(By.id("foo"), function (element) {
    return element.getText();
}).then(function (text) {
    console.log(text);
});

browser.quit();
```

This example can be executed and should produce this output:

```
stale: retrying
stale: retrying
stale: retrying
stale: retrying
stale: retrying
stale: retrying
stale: retrying
stale: retrying
stale: retrying
stale: retrying
foo text
foo text
```

All of the `stale: retrying` lines and the first `foo text` are produced by the code that uses `retryOnStaleIllustrate`. The last `foo text` line is produced by the code that uses `retryOnStale`.

Comment: The same error `UnknownError: unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: Error: element is not attached to the page document` is still coming up. I put a `console.log()` in the `.thenCatch()` block of `retryOnStale()` but nothing is logged when the error comes up. The `console.log(text);` line also does not log anything when the error comes up. It seems the error is still not being caught. Any ideas as to why this might be happening?

Comment: Are you able to execute the example I've put in my answer? I've just modified the code because there was a problem with using the same function name for illustration purposes and for the final version of the `retryOnStale`. I've also added the output it should produce.

Comment: When I run your code, I get the same results that you do. However, when I try to use your solution (`retryOnStale()`) in my test, the error that is thrown is not a `StaleElementReferenceError`, but an `UnknownError`, which for whatever reason is not being caught in the `.thenCatch()` block.

Comment: I forgot to mention in the original post that this error does not come up every time I run the test, but only occasionally. Maybe this information is of use in some way?

Comment: The fact that the problem is intermittent is not unexpected. That's usually what happens with `StaleElementReferenceError`. I've never had an `UnknownError` generated by Selenium. I did not make much of it when I saw it in your question because I thought maybe something else could have been interfering with the exception propagation. When you say `UnknownError` is not caught by `.thenCatch()` you mean to say if you put a `console.log(err);` right at the start of the function passed to `.thenCatch()`, you don't get a dump of that error at al to the consolel?

Comment: Yeah I figured that the problem should be intermittent, but just wanted to clarify that it was indeed intermittent. And that's correct, I added a `console.log(someString);` but nothing was printed when the `UnknownError` was thrown.

Comment: Edit: `UnknownError` still occasionally comes up even when navigating from different pages to the page with the stale element.